# How to use TSQL for generating Json

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, json

I'm trying to design source document for mongodb from data already existing in tabular database sqlserver/mysql.

For practicing i've prepared three table customer,product & order transaction, with schema as below

```
USE scratch
GO

CREATE TABLE Customer(customer_id int identity(1,1), FirstName varchar(100),LastName varchar(100));

Create TAble Product(Product_id int identity(1,1), Name varchar(100), Price numeric(18,2), Unit varchar(10));


CREATE TABLE OrderTransaction(Tr_id int identity(1,1), customer_id int, Product_id int ,Quantity int, TotalCost numeric, trdate datetime, weigh int , weighunit varchar(100));


INSERT INTO Customer(FirstName,LastName)

SELECT 'Harry','G'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jenne','G'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Gill','G'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Tom','G'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bai','G'



INSERT INTO Product(Name,Price, Unit )
SELECT 'Sugar',100,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Olive Oil',500,'litre'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Loreal Face Wash',200,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FLour',400,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Onion',20,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Potato',10,'kg'



INSERT INTO OrderTransaction(customer_id,Product_id,Quantity,TotalCost,trdate,weigh,weighunit)
SELECT 1,1,5,500,GETDATE()-40,5,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,1,2500,GETDATE()-40,5,'litre'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3,5,500,GETDATE()-30,5,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4,1,200,GETDATE()-30,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5,5,100,GETDATE(),5,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,6,5,50,GETDATE(),5,'kg'

UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,5,500,GETDATE()-40,5,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,1,2500,GETDATE()-40,5,'litre'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,3,5,500,GETDATE()-30,5,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,4,1,200,GETDATE()-30,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,5,5,100,GETDATE(),5,'kg'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,6,5,50,GETDATE(),5,'kg'
```

I've tried Json Path in sql server 2016 but didn't find any documentation
to group transaction on basis of customer, it create each transaction as a document.

```
select a.customer_id as 'Customer.customer_id' 
,FirstName as 'Customer.FirstName'
,LastName as 'Customer.LastName'
,Tr_id as 'Customer.AllTransaction.Tr_id'
,b.Product_id as 'Customer.AllTransaction.Product_id'
,Quantity as 'Customer.AllTransaction.Quantity'
,TotalCost as 'Customer.AllTransaction.TotalCost'
,p.Name as 'Customer.AllTransaction.ProductName'


from Customer a
inner join OrderTransaction b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
inner join Product p
on b.Product_id=p.Product_id
FOR JSON PATH
```

I would like write a query to prepare json like:

```
[
  {
    "customer_id": 1,
    "FirstName": "Harry",
    "LastName": "G",
    "totalsales": 3850.0,
    "LastTransactionDate": "2014-12-1208: 42: 00.000Z",
    "AllTransctionList": [
      {
        "Tr_id": 1,
        "Product_id": 1,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 500,
        "ProductName": "Sugar"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 2,
        "Product_id": 2,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "TotalCost": 2500,
        "ProductName": "Olive Oil"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 3,
        "Product_id": 3,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 500,
        "ProductName": "Loreal Face Wash"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 4,
        "Product_id": 4,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "TotalCost": 200,
        "ProductName": "FLour"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 5,
        "Product_id": 5,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 100,
        "ProductName": "Onion"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 6,
        "Product_id": 6,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 50,
        "ProductName": "Potato"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "customer_id": 2,
    "FirstName": "Jenne",
    "LastName": "G",
    "totalsales": 3850.0,
    "LastTransactionDate": "2014-12-1208: 42: 00.000Z",
    "AllTransctionList": [
      {
        "Tr_id": 1,
        "Product_id": 1,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 500,
        "ProductName": "Sugar"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 2,
        "Product_id": 2,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "TotalCost": 2500,
        "ProductName": "Olive Oil"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 3,
        "Product_id": 3,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 500,
        "ProductName": "Loreal Face Wash"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 4,
        "Product_id": 4,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "TotalCost": 200,
        "ProductName": "FLour"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 5,
        "Product_id": 5,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 100,
        "ProductName": "Onion"
      },
      {
        "Tr_id": 6,
        "Product_id": 6,
        "Quantity": 5,
        "TotalCost": 50,
        "ProductName": "Potato"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. You state both mysql and sqlserver. The solution will be greatly different for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started you might use something like

```
SELECT a.customer_id as 'customer_id' 
,FirstName as 'FirstName'
,LastName as 'LastName'
,Tr_id as 'Tr_id'
,Quantity as 'Quantity'
,TotalCost as 'TotalCost'
from Customer a 
inner join OrderTransaction AllTransactionList
on a.customer_id=AllTransactionList.customer_id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Instead of joining OrderTransaction you might get your product data first or use a subselect in the select list like in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-json-output-automatically-with-auto-mode-sql-server) example (Query3).

Like:

```
USE scratch
GO




SELECT a.customer_id     AS 'customer_id' 
,FirstName               AS 'FirstName'
,LastName                AS 'LastName'
,LastTransactionDate
,totalsales
,Tr_id                   AS 'Tr_id'
,ProductName
,Quantity                AS 'Quantity'
,TotalCost               AS 'TotalCost'
FROM 
(SELECT c.customer_id 
,FirstName
,LastName 
,MAX(trdate) LastTransactionDate
,SUM(TotalCost)totalsales

FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN OrderTransaction o
ON c.customer_id=o.customer_id
GROUP BY  
c.customer_id 
,FirstName
,LastName )a

INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    o.Tr_id
    ,o.customer_id
    ,p.Name AS ProductName
    ,o.Quantity
    ,o.TotalCost
    ,o.trdate
    ,o.weigh
    ,o.weighunit 
    FROM OrderTransaction o
    INNER JOIN Product p
    ON o.Product_id=p.Product_id)AllTransactionList

ON a.customer_id=AllTransactionList.customer_id

FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: thanks it's working well with sqlserver, and i got your point of using subselect/ subquery. Just editing your code for the desired result and helping other